# The potential energy of universal gravitation with dynamic mass

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

Everyone knows that the potential energy is generally represented by -GMm/r.
Now, consider the M will decrease or increase depending on time or the m's position (we can think m moves in v). What will happen to the m's mechanical-energy conservation?

Answer (score 0):

$1$. If the mass of $M$ changes it is obviously caused by external means. And the system is no longer isolated.

$2$. When it moves in the gravitational field its velocity is not constant. The total energy is conserved.

$$
-\frac{GMm}{r_1}+\frac{mv_1^2}{2}=-\frac{GMm}{r_2}+\frac{mv_2^2}{2}
$$